# auditd rule for number of logins

Tags: debian-squeeze, auditd

I am using `Debian squeeze` and installed `auditd` on it.

When I run `aureport` it always shows `Number of logins = 0` and `Number of failed logins = 0.`

What rule should be added in audit rules for recording these parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-w /var/log/faillog -p wa -k logins

-w /var/log/lastlog -p wa -k logins
```

the above two rules can help with watching logins .. wi capture both failed and successful logins